# perl - preserve first three words from a string

Tags: perl

I am trying to remove last few words from a string to reduce the length of a string.consider my example string below.

```
my $str = "Today is Wednesday April 23 2014";
print substr( $str, 0, rindex( $str, ' ' ) - index($str, ' ') -4 );
```

Value of string varies , basically I would like to preserve first 3 words or in other words remove last 3 words.

I know by my approach I am not doing in an efficient way, I would like to get inputs from experts here on doing it in more efficient way.

I would like my output to be only first 3 words `Today is Wednesday`

Comment: `$str =~ s/\S+(\s+\S+){2}\K.*//`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the string into words, then return the first three:

```
my $str = "Today is Wednesday April 23 2014";
my @first_three = (split ' ', $str)[0 .. 2];
print "@first_three\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
my $str = "Today is Wednesday April 23 2014";
print join ' ', (split /\s+/, $str)[0..2];
```

Comment: If you think you want `split /\s+/` then you almost certainly should be writing `split ' '` instead. If you are splitting `$_` then it is the default, so that just `split` is the same as `split ' ', $_`. Note that it must be a *string* containing a single space: `split / /` is different

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you have a character limit that you need to keep to, rather than wanting just the first three words of every string. Otherwise a string like

```
I am a spectacular Perl programmer of the very best kind
```

would be truncated to just

```
I am a
```

Given your example string and supposing a character limit of 22 you could write something like this. It matches an initial string up to 22 characters loing, with the restriction that the string must end with a non-space character just before either a space character or the end of the object text

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = "Today is Wednesday April 23 2014";

my ($abbrev) = $str =~ /^(.{0,22})(?<=\S)(?=\s|$)/;

print $abbrev;
```

**output**

```
Today is Wednesday
```